# How to create context menu like in Twitter?

Tags: android

I would like to create one feature in my app like in Twitter app for android. When you use it you have list of tweets. Every item has a text and button. When you click on a button a horizontal menu slides in. I`m wondering how to do something like that ? I know that I need to set OnClickListener for button. That is easy but how to slide in this menu ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This control is called QuickAction. Seen it here:
http://www.londatiga.net/it/how-to-create-quickaction-dialog-in-android/

Comment: Thanks. That is what I was looking for. But tbh I was sure that there will be some native API solution. At least I`ll learn something new :)

Answer (score 0):

Use an animation: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/animation.html